# Usar Retrofit para popular um RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, web-service, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Preciso trazer uma lista de cidades em um `RecyclerView` de um `WebService` usando o `Retrofit`. Mas a minha `List` esta vindo `null`.

Tenho uma `Class cidades` com os dados que preciso pegar do `WebService`, a `Class DadosCidades` onde configuro o `Retrofit`.

A minha Interface DataServer:

```
public interface DataServer {
@GET("cidade-nome.php?nome=rio")
Call<List<Cidades>> getCidades();
}
```

O Adapter CityListAdapter:

```
public class CityListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CityListAdapter.CityViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Cidades> cidadesList;


public CityListAdapter(Context context, List<Cidades> cidadesList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cidadesList = cidadesList;
}


@Override
public CityListAdapter.CityViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


   View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_row_view, viewGroup, false);

    return new CityViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CityListAdapter.CityViewHolder cityViewHolder, int i) {

    cityViewHolder.txtNome.setText(cidadesList.get(i).getNome());
    cityViewHolder.txtSigla.setText(cidadesList.get(i).getSigla_estado());
    cityViewHolder.txtLatitude.setText(cidadesList.get(i).getLatitude());
    cityViewHolder.txtLongitude.setText(cidadesList.get(i).getLongitude());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return cidadesList.size();
}

public class CityViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtNome;
    TextView txtSigla;
    TextView txtLatitude;
    TextView txtLongitude;

    public CityViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtNome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        txtSigla = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSigla);
        txtLatitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
        txtLongitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
    }
}
}
```

Um `xml` single_row_view, com o `TextView` para o `RecyclerView` e a minha `Activity` onde quero exibir a lista de cidades.

Activity SearchActivity :

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CityListAdapter adapter;
    List<Cidades> cidadesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        cidadesList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_notice_list);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DataServer dataServer = DadosCidades.getDadosCidades().create(DataServer.class);

        Call<List<Cidades>> call = dataServer.getCidades();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cidades>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Cidades>> call, Response<List<Cidades>> response) {

                cidadesList = response.body();

                Log.d("SearchActivity", cidadesList.toString());

                adapter = new CityListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cidadesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Cidades>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

E por fim o xml activity_search:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activity.SearchActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_notice_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

No entanto a minha `cidadesList = new ArrayList<>();` vem `size = 0`
Já vi vários tutoriais e até agora não consegui resolver.

Comment: Já verificou se no endpoint está vindo os dados?

Comment: Sim, os dados não chegam, está tudo null. E não entendo o motivo.

Comment: Então, talvez o problema seja na API, tente "bater" nesse endpoint com o postman para recuperar as infos. Se lá vir o problema é no app, se não, provavelmente, na API

Answer (score 0):

O metódo onResponse te dá apenas um retorno, contudo pode não ter sido o de código 200 (como se esperaria). Tenta jogar no log **response.code()** pra ver.
Além disso, você pode usar um if com **response.isSuccessful()** pra ter certeza do retorno e tratar as exceções.